# How to match .c and .h properly?

Tags: c, project, header-files

I have a C project and I really don't get how to manage .c and .h.
I've been using a method for years but now I have to create codes without any warnings, so I need to change the way I do it.

Here is how I'm doing it:

Each .c have a .h with the same name. Even main.c has a main.h.

In each .c, I include the matching .h, so I have only one include per .c.
In main.h, I include all the libraries I need, like stdio stdlib and so on. I also declare my enumerations and structures there.

Finally, in every  other .h, I include the main.h which contains the structures, enums and libraries.

I understand that by doing that, I call main.h a lot of time, but I use the `#ifndef` and `#define` in every .h.
Also, I each .h contains the prototypes of the functions in their corresponding .c

How should I manage .c and .h?

I forgot to mention that the problem is that I get a warning for every single function: "implicit declaration of function"

Here is an example with four files :

main.c :

```
#include "main.h"

int main() 
{
    // code
}
int save(Player players[2], int currentPlayer)
{
    // code
}
int load(Player players[2], int* currentPlayer)
{
    // code
}
```

main.h :

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef enum Direction Direction;
typedef enum Orientation Orientation;
typedef enum ShipType ShipType;
typedef enum CaseType CaseType;
typedef enum Status Status;
typedef enum PlayerType PlayerType;

enum Direction
{
    Nord=0, Est=1, Sud=2, Ouest=3
};
enum Orientation
{
    None=0, Horizontal=1, Vertical=2
};
enum ShipType
{
    SousMarin=1, Destroyer=2, Croiseur=3, Cuirasse=4
};
enum CaseType
{
    Undiscovered=0, Empty=1, Hit=2, Detected=3, Discovered=5
};

enum Status
{
    Undamaged=0, Damaged=1, Drowned=2
};

enum PlayerType
{
    Human=0, Computer=1
};

typedef struct Map Map;
typedef struct Ship Ship;
typedef struct Player Player;

struct Map
{
    int width, height;
    int* cases;
};

struct Ship
{
    int x, y, length, firstShoot, color;
    int hasBeenDiscovered;
    Orientation orientation;
    ShipType type;
    Status status;
};

struct Player
{
    int totalShips;
    int activeShips;
    Map map[2];
    char lastMoves[5][128];
    Ship* ships;
    PlayerType type;
    int shipcolor[4];
    int shipNumber[4];
    int color;
};

int save(Player players[2], int currentPlayer);
int load(Player players[2], int* currentPlayer);

#endif // MAIN_H
```

IA.c :

```
#include "IA.h"

int IA(Player* IA, Player* enemy)
{
    // code
}

// And all my other functions
```

IA.h :

```
#ifndef IA_H
#define IA_H

#include "main.h"

int IA(Player* IA, Player* enemy);
void endIATurn(Player* IA);

int enemyShipDiscovered(Map map, int* x, int* y, int SousMarinSpecific);
Ship* bestFriendlyActiveShip(Ship* ships, int totalShips, int SousMarinSpecific);
int friendlyShipDiscovered(Ship** ship, Ship* ships, Map map, int totalShips, int SousMarinSpecific);
int hitShipButNotDrowned(Player* IA, Player enemy, int totalShips, int* x, int* y);

int hasAtLeastOneMoveableShip(Player player);
int hasUndiscoveredCases(Player player);

void getUndiscoveredCoordoonnees(Map map, int* x, int* y);
int findNextCaseToShootAt(Map map, Ship ship, int* a, int* b);

#endif // IA_H
```

All my other .h are like IA.h

Comment: Considering the way you handle the files, I was more expecting a *duplicate* declaration... Could we see an excerpt of a `.c` and its corresponding `.h`?

Comment: And you've been getting those warnings for _years_ and not thought to do anything about it until now!?  If you have an "implicit declaration", the compiler cannot see the declaration at the point a function is called - somehow you have not included the header or the header is not correct.  It is far from clear from your text description what you are doing; post some examples.

Comment: post a [mcve] please

Comment: The problem is probably that you use functions in the `main` function from other files without including the headers from those files. It's not enough to include `main.h` in `main.cpp`, you need to include the headers that contain each function that you use (so for example if your `main` function uses a function from `foo.c`, you need to include `foo.h` in `main.c` or `main.h`). Similarly, if you want to use a function from `bar.c` in `foo.c`, you need to include `bar.h` in `foo.c`.

Comment: The `.h` file should have only `#include` for headers it directly depends on.  The `.c` or `.cpp` file should include its own header, plus all the headers it directly depends on.  Your headers should have header guards and/or `#pragma once`, depending on your compiler.  All the stuff you are putting in `main.h` I'd put in `common.h`, just to make it more clear.  For larger projects, consider making header-headers.

Comment: I added an example with four files. If I include my other .h in my main.h, I get a lot of errors "unknow type Player, Map Ship"

Comment: So which symbols are implicitly declared in this?  Post the error log too (vernatim - copy & paste not transcribed).

Answer (score 2):

For `foo.h` and `foo.c`:

- Use `foo.h` to tell other source files about things that `foo.c` provides. So `foo.h` will declare functions that are (a) defined in `foo.c` and (b) called from other source files. It will also declare any types or other things that those functions need or that other source files need in able to be able to use the functions.
- In `foo.h`, only use `#include` to include header files that `foo.h` itself needs.
- In `foo.c`, use `#include "foo.h"`. This has two purposes: (1) It declares things that `foo.c` may need, without having to duplicate those declarations in `foo.c`. (2) It ensures that `foo.c` is using the same declarations that other source files see when they include `foo.h`, so any conflicts between declarations in `foo.h` and definitions in `foo.c` will produce compiler warnings or error messages.
- If `foo.c` needs any headers that `foo.h`, include them in `foo.c`, not `foo.h`. Similarly, if `foo.c` has any functions that it uses for itself but does not expect other source files to use, declare them only in `foo.c`. Keep things that are just for `foo.c` inside `foo.c`. Use `foo.h` only for exporting things to other source files.

If there are any types or other declarations used by your program generally:

- Put them in a suitably named file (e.g., `bar.h` for types involving some `bar` concept) and include it. Largely, you can treat `bar.h` as a pair `bar.h` and `bar.c` described above except that `bar.c`is empty.

Generally, there is no reason to make a `main.h`. Usually, `main.c` uses things that other source files provide and does not provide things for other sources to use (except that `main` is called by the C run-time start-up code).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. Divide your functions in different .c files as you already do. For every .c create a .h
2. In every .h insert its *include guard*:

   1. Within the include guard, start by including the .h of the libraries you need to *declare* your functions or to define structs, e.g. `#include <stdlib.h>` if you use `size_t` parameters.
   2. Within the include guard, insert the structs, enums, ... you need exported
   3. Within the include guard, insert the function declarations.
3. In every .c start by including its corresponding .h, then include other libraries needed to implement your functions, then put in the definitions.
4. Don't make a `main.h` or `common.h`, unless you have extremely good reasons for it (I know this will be commented against, but everyone has its style).

In `main.c` include what you need. You'll be including much less than you think.

Comment: If I understand it correctly I'll have to insert in every .h my structs and enums (if I use them in the .h) ? I can't just declare them one time ?

Comment: Your question should be "why do I get these errors" not "how do I organise my files" - the latter has little to do with your errors, and is largely opinion based.  If the solution is file organisation; you will get that in the answer - do not preempt answers by asking for a particular solution - rather invite all solutions.

Comment: @Drakalex: Each structure or enumeration type should be defined in only one header.  If other headers need that information too, then those headers should include the sole header that defines the structure or enumeration.  Header guards deal with residual problems.  This implements two concepts from Agile Development: SPOT — Single Point of Truth, and DRY — Don't Repeat Yourself.  Make each header self-contained (it compiles without any other headers being included first) and idempotent (it doesn't matter how often it is included; that's what header guards are for).